# design to send multiple type http request

Tags: rust, asynchronous

I have to send multiple HTTP requests where their payload will be different, type will be different, headers will be different, URL will be different etc. The code I have right now is

```
pub async fn make_login_request(
    client: &Client,
    host: &String,
    credentials: &HashMap<String, String>,
) -> Result<(), reqwest::Error> {
    client
        .post(
            &(String::from("https://")
                + &String::from(host)
                + &String::from("/[URL]")),
        )
        .json(&credentials)
        .header(
            CONTENT_TYPE,
            "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
        )
        .send()
        .await?;
    Ok(())
}
```

This code makes a POST call, for GET call, it will be like

```
client
    .get(
        &(String::from("https://")
            + &String::from(host)
            + &String::from("/[URL]")),
    )
 ...
```

But, I will have to create a different function for GET call. Here, I will have to pass hostname, URL, headers, payload. So, what is the best approach I should take to write this code and handle the response?

Comment: Where is `Client` from?

Comment: @WinstonEwert, it is ```reqwest::Client```

Comment: Have you tried this method? https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.8/reqwest/struct.Client.html#method.request